# How to show a process progressing without knowing when it would finish

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When I have a process that I know when it would finishes, I would use a progress bar. But what can I use to show that a process is progressing but I have no idea when it would finishes?

Is there any special control for this in WPF?

Answer (score 8):

Why not use a ProgressBar with `IsIndeterminate` set to `true` ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator) to show that the application is in progress.